# Por que servidor requer portas abertas em um modem de acesso mas o cliente não?

Tags: redes, cliente-servidor, chat, firewall

Me surgiu essa dúvida em quanto eu estava pensando em criar um chat para comunicação direta entre dois computadores seja local ou remotos. Esse será meu primeiro projeto de estudo em que eu aplico comunicação por rede. Então eu percebi que para criar um servidor é necessário abrir portas no modem de acesso a internet, mas para que o cliente se comunique não. Por que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O cliente não recebe requisições, ele só as emite. O servidor recebe requisições, então precisa ser permitido que isso aconteça. Se permitisse todas portas teria uma grande área de ataque através de requisições de exploração.

Na verdade não é que precise abrir as portas para o cliente, elas estão todas abertas, não tem porque fechar portas de saída a não ser que não confie no que está rodando na máquina, mas aí porta aberta é o menor dos problemas.

É como um show, uma festa fechada, em evento, há controle de quem entra, não de quem sai. Todo mundo pode sair, só quem tem permissão pode entrar.

Claro que todo cliente pode ser um servidor também. Em comunicações ponto a ponto são assim. O ponto a ponto precisa sempre saber o endereço do ponto para iniciar a comunicação.

A requisição inicial de comunicação precisa da porta aberta, mas depois isso não é mais problema na maioria das arquiteturas já que a conexão pode ser mantida aberta, aí fica como se fossem dois clientes se comunicado.

Comment: Entendi.
Então no caso se eu quisesse que dois computadores troquem informações entre si, levando em consideração que eles não precisem ter portas abertas no modem, eu teria que utilizar um servidor fora das duas redes  onde estarão os clientes? Sendo o servidor apenas responsável por redirecionar mensagens, é assim que serviços como Whatsapp e outros mensageiros funcionam?

Comment: Acredito que tanto cliente quanto servidor usem portas para se comunicarem, sua resposta dá a entender o contrário. Ou não sei lá... Caso o cliente necessite uma porta deveria estar mais explícito...

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds é isso mesmo, se quiser fazer comunicação ponto a ponto só se os clientes sejam servidores também. Para não exigir isto precisa de um servidor pelo menos pra iniciar a conversa, depois dá pra para eles se comunicarem diretamente mantendo a comunicação aberta, aí não precisa mais de requisições. Cada comunicador tem seu jeito, mas acredito que o mais comum é o servidor só existir para iniciar a comunicação entre pontos. Em alguns casos ele quer centralizar a comunicação e ter um histórico, aí o servidor mantêm toda conversa nele. Jogos são assim também, até pq é um "chat" deles

Comment: @MagicHat Acredito que "não é que precisa abrir as portas para o cliente, eles estão todas abertas." indica claramente que usa portas.

Comment: É parece mesmo, a pergunta é ampla e não e clara, pois nem faz referência a portas físicas ou lógicas... Como geralmente suas respostas abordam uma amplitude maior, achei conveniente mencionar... Mas talvez vc precisasse dá pergunta melhor elaborada